# New Ender 3 v2: the printer backs the filament completely out of the extruder

Tags: creality-ender-3

I just bought a new Ender 3v2 from MicroCenter. When I attempt to start a print, the printer backs the filament completely out of the extruder, up the feeding tube and out of the machine. I'm running PLA+ in it. The first time, the nozzle was blocked, but it is still doing it and the nozzle is not obstructed in any way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE, your question wasn't expressing the actual problem, so I changed the title for you. Too bad you are experiencing problems! Are you saying that the filament when properly primed in the nozzle travels backwards completely instead of advancing to the nozzle? Can you show us the first 30 lines of G-code of the print file? Alternatively link the file in comments. You haven't changed anything to the firmware and the connector of the Extruder isn't accidentally reversed into the socket of either the controller board or the extruder stepper motor?

Comment: My 12 year old assembled the printer for me.. as far as the G-code for the file, I’ll have to have him help me with that, I’m totally new to printing, he’s been doing it for over a year

Comment: Have you managed to print something? If so it sounds as of it is incorrectly assembled.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for the suggestions.. I took it apart and reassembled it (my 12 year old originally built it, he’s usually good at these things) we found that the wires were reversed (at least according to him). It’s printing great now

Comment: You're welcome to hinting to the solution. Thanks for getting back to post the answer, please do not forget to accept it after 48 hours to mark it solved, just tick the check mark under the up and down arrow in front of the answer.